# Find the value of an array by referring to the index number in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

In python, calling the value of a list by only referring to its index number is done by

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]
return array[0]
```

returns

> 1

Is there a similar way to do this in java? I have only been able to find calling values of an array and getting their index using indexOf().

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordList.add("desk");
wordList.add("monitor");

return wordList[1];
```

Returns error

> array required, but ArrayList found
> return wordList[1];
> ^

I would want it to return the value that is in index 1, which is 'monitor'

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By using an **array**.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
return array[0]; // for 1, for 2 use array[1], etc.
```

You can *also* do it with a `List`. But there you need to call [`List.get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) instead of `[int]`. Like,

```
List<String> wordList = List.of("desk", "monitor");
return wordList.get(1); // "monitor"
```

**Or** with a `String[]` just like an `int[]`

```
String[] wordArray = { "desk", "monitor" };
return wordArray[1]; // "monitor"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `wordList` is an Object of type ArrayList (ArrayList Object) and NOT an array.

Try creating an array of type String:

```
String[] wordList = {"array", "items", "here"};
return wordList[2] //Would equal "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Java array with [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). An `ArrayList` is a type of [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) backed by an array.

I don't know Python, so I'll address this only from a Java point of view.

```
// foo is an array of int, and contains 12 elements
int [] foo = new foo [12]; 

// bar is an array of int, with 7 elements. 
// the initial values are specified
int [] bar = {14, 92, -42, 48, 0, 0, 13};
```

An element is addressed as you expect:
`System.out.println (bar [2]); // prints -42`

If you want to fix your example using an array, the code might look like this:

```
String [] wordList = {"desk", "monitor"};
System.out.println (wordList[1]); // monitor
```

Collections are more flexible than arrays. One consideration is that an array has a fixed size, while most Collection Objects will increase their sizes as needed. Suppose an array is used, and it is discovered it is too small. To continue, a new array would have to be created, the contents of the old array would be copied into the new array, and the old array discarded.

If you wanted to fix your Java example to use an ArrayList, it might look like this, with a call to [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)):

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordList.add("desk");
wordList.add("monitor");

return wordList.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Is there a similar way to do this in java? I have only been able to find calling values of an array and getting their index using indexOf(). ..."*

Not for a *List*.  In *Java*, the *bracket syntax* is used exclusively for *array notation*.